# Performing Sensitivity Analysis on Suitability Model using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.5, weighted-overlay

I am working on a suitability analysis model for a landfill site selection. Basically, I am using GIS-based MCDA so I have 11 factor layers/maps that I considered for the analysis. I have already standardized these factor maps. Now, I am using the Weighted Sum tool to aggregate/combine these layers, each layers having a corresponding weight. What I want to do in sensitivity analysis is to iterate the weighted sum in my model where each iteration uses a different combination of weights for each factor layer.

How do I do this in ModelBuilder?

[image]

The combination of weights that I want to use for each iteration of the weighted sum is shown in the attachment below.Of course, I still need to do way more iterations than what I showed here.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @BERA. I attached a screenshot of the model I initially built.

Comment: As for the iterator and saving the weight in a table, do you mean using Iterator Tables and saving the table of weights as a spreadsheet file?

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting a duplicate. It would be easy to solve this using Python. If you want to i can post a python solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Python way of doing it. Either run it after the model or import it into the model. Output rasters will be named Sumraster_1, Sumraster_2 ... First row in the csv is the raster names, next rows are each iteration.

[image]

```
import arcpy, csv

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\database.gdb' #Rasters named in the csv file need to be here and output weighted rasters will be placed here.
weights = r'C:\Test\Weights.csv'
valuefield = 'VALUE'

with open(weights, 'r') as csvfile:
    rowreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rasternames = next(rowreader)
    count = 1
    for row in rowreader:
        outWeightedSum = arcpy.sa.WeightedSum(arcpy.sa.WSTable([list(a) for a in zip(rasternames, [valuefield]*7, [float(r) for r in row])]))
        outWeightedSum.save('Sumraster_{0}'.format(count))
        count+=1
```

If your workspace is a folder you need to add file extension, for example: `outWeightedSum.save('Sumraster_{0}.tif'.format(count))` and of course in the csv file.

Comment: I tried to run the python script but I encountered this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Test\thanos.py", line 12, in <module>
    outWeightedSum = arcpy.sa.WeightedSum(arcpy.sa.WSTable([list(a) for a in zip(rasternames, [valuefield]*4, [float(r) for r in row])]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

Failed to execute (Script1).

Comment: Note that in my csv the iterations are rows. @Mak do you use dot (.) or comma (,) as decimal separator? 0,7 or 0.7? I probably needs to be dot, or you need to change the field delimiter in the csv from comma to for example semi-colon (;) and change `rowreader = csv.reader(csvfile)` to `rowreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')`

Comment: @BERA I found out that the cause of the error was on my csv file, probably not converted correctly (it was originally in .xlsx) for whatever reasons I dont know why. This was not obvious until I opened the file in Notepad. Some unwanted commas were inserted after every row. Anyways, the script is now running! Thanks a lot for the help. Very much appreciated!

Comment: Nice! If it solved your question could you accept my answer with the checkbox?

Comment: I tried using the script for 11 rasters and 203 iterations but error says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Test\OAT.py", line 12, in <module>
    outWeightedSum = arcpy.sa.WeightedSum(arcpy.sa.WSTable([list(a) for a in zip(rasternames, [valuefield]*11, [float(r) for r in row])]))
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 6786, in WeightedSum
    in_weighted_sum_table)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)...

Comment: Is it outputting any raster?